# Create Submenu with Redux Framework _WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I have created a submenu in the Appearance Menu:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rKA2.png)

Now I wanna show the sections and fields in the submenu named Theme Options but it did not work.
I try to use file sample-config in Redux framwork and change some parameters
Here is the config option:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T225J.png)

And the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvbyX.png)

Help me find and fix this problem!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Lead dev of Redux here.  ;)

https://docs.redux.io/configuration/global_arguments.html#menu-type
https://docs.redux.io/configuration/global_arguments.html#page-parent

Add those in your Redux config, and there you go.  :)